# locally convex vector space, functional analysis, seperation theorem

Tags: functional-analysis, locally-convex-spaces

> Let $(E,\tau)$ be a locally convex $\mathbb{K}$-vector-space and $A\subseteq E$ with $0\in A$. The following statements are equivalent:
>
> (1) $A$ is closed and convex
>
> (2) It exists a subset $B\subseteq E'$ ($E'$ notes the dual space of $E$) with $A=\bigcap_{f\in B}\{\Re(f(x))\leq 1\}$

As a hint it is given, that one should first show, that for every $x\in E\setminus A$ there is an open convex neighborhood $U$ of $x$ such that $U\cap A=\emptyset$

I think this is related to the seperation theorem of Hahn-Banach.

I have no idea on how to proof the hint. :(
Can you get me started?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: To prove the hint: $E\setminus A$ is open and hence a neighborhood of $x$. As $X$ is locally convex it contains a convex neighborhood whose interior is again convex.